# Displaying character input with interactive declaration

Tags: interactive, characters

I have the following code for reading two characters, using the interactive declaration.  When I run the interactive function the input character is not being shown after the description string.

```
(interactive "cOpening delimiter character: \n cClosing delimiter character: \nr")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading a character does not echo the character read. This is true for `interactive` with code `c`, and for functions such as `read-char` and `read-char-exclusive`.

But `read-char-from-minibuffer` does echo the value read.

```lisp
(interactive (list (read-char-from-minibuffer "Char: ")))
```

Comment: Thought it was a bug, as I noticed  the mini-buffer flickering when the user inputs the respective character.